# Kleopatra--Encryption/Decryption Log

Tags: encryption, kleopatra

Looking to make sure I have correct understanding.
Someone sent an encrypted message.  Should have been encrypted with my public key.
I don't believe it was though, and I am wanting to confirm my understanding of things are correct.

In the diag log when I try to decrypt, I get this.

> gpg: encrypted with ECDH key, ID 814A3A50484DFAAE
> gpg: public key decryption failed: No secret key
> gpg: decryption failed: No secret key*

If I do a:  gpg --list-keys
I get:

> *C:\Users\dunns>gpg --list-keys
> [keyboxd]
> ---------
> pub   rsa2048 2021-04-21 [SC]
> 29A573A40EB7667C5C0C0B58F745E2FC7A3331BF
> uid           [ultimate] Some Email Address
> sub   rsa2048 2021-04-21 [E]

> pub   rsa4096 2021-09-15 [SC] [expires: 2023-09-15]
> 56CE148CDAA9170BF89D15BFDB09FEB9D8A9A0BC
> uid           [  full  ] Some Email Address
> sub   rsa4096 2021-09-15 [E] [expires: 2023-09-15]

> pub   rsa2048 2023-08-03 [SCEA] [expires: 2031-08-01]
> DB7C3A5A9141E8103545A06C43F75472E38018BB
> uid           [ultimate] Some Email Address
> sub   rsa2048 2023-08-03 [SEA] [expires: 2031-08-01]
> sub   rsa2048 2023-08-03 [SEA] [expires: 2031-08-01]

So the public key it should have been encrypted with, should I believe correspond to the one listed above:

> pub   rsa2048 2021-04-21 [SC]
> 29A573A40EB7667C5C0C0B58F745E2FC7A3331BF*

How can I tell if the key used to encrypt the stuff, was the public key I sent them? and not some other key they are mistakenly using??
I think the key they are using is not the right one, cause the diag log says
ID 814A3A50484DFAAE
Which I assume is the ID of the pub key used?

Am I correct?
Thank you

Edit: Additional Info
If I go to the PGPTool.org site and encrypt a message using my public key,
Then take the encrypted message and put in Kleopatra to decrypt, It does decrypt
The Diag Log shows

> gpg: encrypted with rsa2048 key, ID 7D282D0969E84107, created 2021-04-21

Which the ID shown in that log does correspond to my private key in Kleo
If I look at the SubKey Details for my private key, the ID is the same as the ID listed as the one being used to encrypt the message.

Comment: What do you get from --list-keys with the `--with-subkey-fingerprint` option?

Comment: Using that option, I pretty much get the same info as doing just --list-keys

Comment: I will also note that my pub key is RSA, the diag log says encrypted with ECDH.  So that should also pretty much rule out my key was used to encrypt?